# Spam SMS on iPhone - any chance of stopping it?

Tags: itunes, sms, spam

Possibly due to some in-app purchase done by a kid before the in-app purchasing was disabled, an iPhone 5S user receives this type of link weekly

[http://wowza1.mobibase.com:8080/apple/*definst*/channel/431/57/57_rtsp.sdp/playlist.m3u8?ticket=](http://wowza1.mobibase.com:8080/apple/_definst_/channel/431/57/57_rtsp.sdp/playlist.m3u8?ticket=).....

Contents:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=250000
chunklist_w2079735267.m3u8?ticket=same as in url
```

It gos to iTunes but does not does anything further on an iMac so I assume it might only do something on an iPhone.

No-one wishes to click it and I cannot find the url or parts of it mentioned on the net.

I know I can sms STOP to a number if I knew if the number who sent the spam would react and not just be happy I sent a reply and double their effort

Any suggestions as to my next step?

Answer (score 1):

I've never had to block a number but this might work:
Open up the Settings app and go to `Messages -> Blocked -> Add new`, this should block all calls and text messages from that number (you have to add it in your Contacts before you can block it, unfortunately)

Comment: Ok I'll try it.